# cx-freeze + linux + python 2.6 + wxpython

Tags: wxpython

Not able to create standalone python binary package

1) The binary package works only on the  machine on which it is build
2) There is always an error with respect console.py dependent on cx_freeze and wx libraries (.so files).
3) Tried the rpath trick suggested at this link http://wiki.wxpython.org/CreatingStandaloneExecutables
4) I have also experimented with GUI2exe , but still dependency problem exists.

Please let me know if there is working python script to solve these dependence problem of cx_freeze and wx._core (.so) files.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You might try using pyinstaller (http://pyinstaller.org) instead because Freeze cannot handle binary files.